# Nonlinear differential equation. $p^3-4px^4+8yx^3=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Nonlinear differential equation.
Let $p=\dfrac{dy}{dx}$
$$p^3-4px^4+8yx^3=0$$

I tried to make $y$ alone and take derivative wrt. $x$ as

$$y=\dfrac{p^3}{-8x^3}+\dfrac{xp}{2}$$

then

$$y'=p=\dfrac{-3}{8x^3}p^2p'+\dfrac{3}{8x^4}p^3$$

but cannot solve for $p$

Comment: Is this an exercise from a book, or a "real life" problem ?

Comment: it is a problem that one of my friend send me from whatsapp, I couldnot solve it. By the way I took this diff eq. lecture 3 years ago :), but it seems I forgot to solve these equations...

Comment: This is certainly not an elementary one. But you didn't really answer my question.

Answer (score 3):

$$p^3-4px^4+8yx^3=0$$
$$(y')^3-4y'x^4+8yx^3=0$$
Change the variable $x$ ( $ \dfrac {dy}{dx} \to 2x\dfrac {dy}{dx^2}$) :
$$(\dfrac {dy}{dx^2}2x)^3-8x^5\dfrac {dy}{dx^2}+8yx^3=0$$
$$y'^3-uy'+y=0$$
$$y=uy'-y'^3$$
Where $u=x^2$.

This is [Clairaut's differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clairaut%27s_equation).

Comment: how you came up with that substitution?

Comment: @Jale'dejaleuffnejale you try different changes of variable and see how to make it works.

Answer (score 1):

From
$$ p=\dfrac{-3}{8x^3}p^2p'+\dfrac{3}{8x^4}p^3$$
one has
$$ p'=\frac1xp-\frac{8x^3}{3}p^{-2}. $$
This is a Bernoulli equation. Letting $u=p^{3}$ and then
$$ u'=3p^{2}p'=3p^{2}\bigg(\frac1xp-\frac{8x^3}{3}p^{-2}\bigg)=\frac{3}{x}u-8x^3 $$
which is a linear DE and you can do the rest.

Comment: should be $p^{-1}$ instead of $-2$ it seems, and there is 8 is missing

$p'=1/x*p-8/3x^3 p^{-1}$

Comment: Yes, you are right. I forgot to type $8$.

Comment: Note that your first, copied equation was wrong or incomplete in the question. The derivative of the term $xp/2$ is missing.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't check before.